# Can I install to a USB key, but place the swap partition on my hard drive?

Tags: installation, usb-drive, swap

Is is possible to do a normal install to a usb key, but place swap partition on internal hard drive?

My Lenovo laptop has 4 primary partitions including 2 recovery. I want to do the above so that I don't wear out my USB.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is certainly possible but I don't know how you'll create an extended part. on your HDD since you already have 4 primary partitions.

Outline:

1. Install Ubuntu normally on USB, manually partition, skip creating swap, boot from USB.
2. Use `sudo mkswap /dev/sdX` to create swap on hard drive.
3. Edit `/etc/fstab` to include the swap partition and automount it.
4. Use `swapon` to turn it on.

Comment: Why not try without the swap? If your computer is not too old it should work fine.

Comment: @RamonSuarez: that's a... "lifestyle" choice ;)

Comment: Yes, correction--I have 3 primary partitions, and one extended. True, I am not sure if I can actually make the logical ext4 on one of the extended.

Comment: @Steve: In that case, as long as there is enough free space on the extended partition, Ubuntu will be able to perfectly install dual-boot in there, including any swap partitions. Problem solved, no USB needed :)

Comment: thanks izx--I actually tried that, but for some reason I was only given the choice of overwriting windows or "something else"-- but perhaps I should try again, with the "something else" option.

Comment: @Steve - yes - something else - you will have to do this manually.

Comment: @Steve, good luck -- I'd recommend asking a separate question if you have any issues with that. BTW if you feel this answered the original USB-swap question adequately, please consider accepting it with the tick/check mark on the left.